# Getting boolean value from input label to Postgres DB

Tags: javascript, html, postgresql

I have a little problem.
I have a HTML form that fills a Postgres database like this :

```
<form method="post">
                        <label for="shortcode"> Shortcode </label>
                        <input type="text" name="shortcode" id="shortcode">

                        <label for="prix"> Price </label>   
                        <input type="number" name="prix" id="prix" >        

                        <label for="taxe"> Tax </label>
                        <input type="texte" name="taxe" id="taxe">  
    </form>
```

The problem is that the 'taxe' label is a boolean type on the database, so when I fill the 'taxe' input with values except "TRUE" and "FALSE" or "T" and "F" I will have an error. I'm not so good on HTML but I tried to add an input checkbox instead of text :

```
<input type="checkbox" id="tax_checkbox" onclick="validate()" name="taxe">
```

and I tried this function :

```
function validate() {
  var isChecked = false;
  if (document.getElementById('tax_checkbox').checked) {
    isChecked = true;
    console.log(isChecked);
  } else {
    isChecked = false;
    console.log(isChecked);
  }
}
```

This is my Pgsql code to take input values to the Database :

```
$shortcode= $_POST['shortcode'];
        $prix= $_POST['prix'];
        $taxe= $_POST['taxe'];

        $sql = "INSERT INTO shortcode (sc_shortcode,prix_ttc_shortcode,taxe_shortcode) VALUES ('".$shortcode."','".$prix."','".$taxe."')";
        $q=pg_query($sql);
```

Finally I get this error : Warning: `pg_query() [function.pg-query]: Query failed: ERROR: invalid input syntax for type boolean: "on" in C:\Users\aspis\Documents\WWW\Create.php on line 17`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `value` attribute to your checkbox and add a hidden input to set the default value for unchecked checkbox:

```
<input type="hidden" name="taxe" value="false" /> 
<input type="checkbox" name="taxe" value="true" />
```

If the checkbox is unchecked, then it will submit the value from the hidden input.

Comment: I didn't thought that it can be so simple !! i'm dumb.
Thank you man it's easier